# Can't access a basic Fabric Azure WebAPI OWIN stateless service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-service-fabric

After following the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi.md), I've succeeded running it on `localhost:8534/simpleprime/api/values/`* having the same result as the tut.

Later publishing the solution to a remote cloud cluster, I couldn't access it using `www.clusterurl:8534/api/values`, timing out each time. Even though I got reassuring event diagnostics from Visual Studio during the deploy.

I've also tried each of the nodes seperetly, going to 
`http://node_ip:8543/simpleprime/api/values`, without any luck

[image: bunch of reassuring diagnostics]

- simpleprime is the appRoot

Comment: What dashboard says?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access your service with OWIN listener on Azure, you should define ports that will be used by your application for the LoadBalancer during cluster creation.

**If you for some reason forgot you can do it later by:**

**SERVICE PART**

1. Go to PackageRoot/**ServiceManifest.xml** of your service with OWIN Listener
2. Define your endpoint directly (so SF will use your definied port number) (in my example 8081)
   [image]
3. Re-publish application to Azure.

**AZURE PART**

1. Go to Azure Portal
2. Find the Load Balancer that is assigned to your SF (LB-nameofyourSF-namofNodeSet)
3. In LoadBalancer settings go to **Probes** and add new probe like on the image below with your Port defined in **ServiceManifest.xml** (*on my example 8081*) and Protocol TCP
   [image]

   4. Add new **Load balancing rule** with your port and probe defined earlier and the correct port mapping (in my example 8081):

[image]

5. Save and now you should be able to access your service on Azure via browser.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the graphic details !

Comment: If there are multiple load balancers in the service fabric setup, then doesn't these rules needs to be added to all the load balancers running the service? I just added the rule to one load balancer and I could not access the service endpoint externally. But after adding the same rule to the other lb, I was able to access the service externally.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, inside the service port config (a.k.a **`ServiceManifest.xml`**) there is a port setting. After changing it to **19080** - the default http port my cluster was listening to, everything started working.

[image: ServiceManifest.xml]

Comment: I thought 19080 was the port for Service Fabric Explorer? At a guess I would say you need to edit the config of your cluster or load balancer in Azure to allow for your port 8543.

Comment: I think it might be the "Custom endpoints" setting in the "Node type configuration" of your cluster.